# What is happening to make my Update/Publish button disabled?

Tags: publish

I'm really wondering... What is WP doing when it disables the Update/Publish button?

It seems to happen every once in a while, and I could not say why in goes disabled sometimes for just a few minutes, but some other times it seems to be permanently disabled.

So what triggers the Update/Publish button to be disabled (and what reenables it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your specific situation, I cannot say whether this is what's causing your issues or not, but this is my best guess.

WordPress has this cool thing called the [Heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/). It pings the server periodically while you're logged in and in the WordPress admin. It does a number of things to help improve the editing experience like auto-save, check if you're logged in, check if someone else is editing your page (or kicks you off), etc.

If the heartbeat doesn't execute successfully (or a variety of other situations), it can cause things like the publish button to be disabled. This is actually a good thing since it prevents you from trying to publish without a connection to the server (and potentially losing your work).

Comment: Ah I guess it's that. I'm developping in a local environement, and sometimes something will fireup and choke the sql.